# laravel make a model have an attribute with value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model called template and field template - when being called it doesn't exist, so how do I create a property or attribute called template when calling it this is being called through ajax. I tried making an accessor but it's not creating the attribute 'template' getTemplateAttribute($value) so I made a with('template') and I can't seem to create the attribute template in my model when being called.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Template extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'templates';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'directory', 'filename', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function template() {
        $this->attributes['template'] = 'test';
    }
}
```

// and when calling it

```
public function show(Template $template)
{
    $template = Template::findOrFail($template->id)->with('template');
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: You need declare your custom attribute in your model.

  protected $appends = ['template'] and then you need to set your custom attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use `appends` in model.. then use get**AppendType**Attribute(); the AppendType must be exact name as appends value..

```
class Template extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'templates';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'directory', 'filename', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    protected appends = ['template'];


    public function getTemplateAttribute() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

then

```
 $template = Template::findOrFail($template->id);
 return $template->template;
```

Comment: im glad it helps.. you can mark this answer if it helps you. :)